# readonly getters for BOOL values in objective-c

Tags: iphone

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  My class has essentially two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isValid;
```

The logic is supposed to be if the name is not nil, then isValid=YES, otherwise NO.  So I wrote that as:

```
- (BOOL)isValid {
    if (self.name)   // breakpoint was set here.
       return YES;
    else 
       return NO;
}
```

I get the opposite effect when I print out the description.  Not sure why.  I tried to step through the debugger for this.  When it stops on this method and I look at the values in self, I look at the `name` property and the value is nil.  But then right after I step into, when the debugger is at the return NO statement, it has the `name` property populated with the correct value.

I guess I could just set the isValid flag when the object is created based on that condition, but I thought I wouldn't have to if it could just read if self.name was nil or not.  Anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  Thanks.

Edited:
My superclass is NSObject.

In this same class, there are two other properties where I essentially have the same type of logic.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *AA;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isCodingRegion;

- (BOOL)isCodingRegion {
    if (self.AA) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

And this logic does work.

Comment: That sounds really wrong. Have you overrided `- (NSString*)name`? Also, what is the super-class of this class?

Comment: How do you print the description?

Comment: You should probably be using the `copy` keyword on the `@property` for `name`. As it stands, you just have a pointer to a string object and that could be changing out from under you.

Comment: Don't you use a lazy getter for `name` ? You might forget to return the initialized value then. That is assuming `isValid` gives you a wrong result once and works fine later, is that correct ?